# Notice local variable can't turn back to null

Tags: typescript

I have the following construct (some code omitted for clarity, e.g. `catch`):

```
import readline from "readline";

let line: readline.Interface | null = null;
try {
  line = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  const question = async (questionText: string) =>
    new Promise<string>(
      (res) =>
        void line.question(`${questionText}\n`, (answer) => void res(answer))
        //       ^--- Object is possibly null
    );
} finally {
  line?.close();
}
```

`rl` is never closed over in the remaining code, and never reassigned. Is this a valid spot for a non-null-assertion, and static analysis just not advanced enough yet to notice? Should i rather convert to an optional chain, to prevent the ever so slight chance for a programmer's error, where someone does reassign `rl` later?

I'd prefer `rl` to be `const` and just `readline.Interface` without `null`, but due to the `try`/`finally` i think this is impossible.

Comment: I suspect the static analysis is going to heavily depend on the type that can be returned by `readline.createInterface`.  If the return type includes `| null` then TypeScript can't make assumptions, it could be `null`.  If there are no static type definitions and it defaults to `any` then TypeScript still can't guarantee that it's not `null`.

Comment: I just checked; the return type does not include `| null`

Comment: Just to elaborate: since `rl` is used in a function (closure over `rl`), it may be, that the function is executed at a much later stage (it could even be stored indefinitely). This means, that if `rl` were to be reassigned to `null` later (which is allowed), `rl` would suddenly be `null` there. However, all code is right there, and can be analyzed. Any reassignment of `rl` would syntactically have to be visible inside of that function. I get, that static analysis is probably not at that point yet, i am just wondering, if my thoughts are correct, and how to solve it.

Comment: `readline.createInterface` doesn't throw, so there's no need for it to be in the `try`. The code you have actually can't catch anything though; you would have to wrap the whole thing in an `async` function and `await` your Promise in order to do that (your `async` isn't doing anything here).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question @Doofus, but definitely don't use a non-null assertion. They are generally bad practise, and imagine in this case someone comes along later and adds some code that *does* allow for `rl` to be null in between your call to `createInterface` and `line.question`. You've now got potentially broken code.

Comment: @ExplosionPills As mentioned, other code was omitted, as it doesn't add anything relevant to the question (apart from the guarantee, that there is no reassignment to `rl`). If i can be sure, that `createInterface` cannot throw, i could hoist it out of the `try` block. However, it's much safer/cleaner, if simply everything is inside the `try`. Then it's both obvious and certain, that there can't be any unhandled exception.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me... are you asking if there is a way to avoid TypeScript complaining about the object possibly being null without a specific null check?

Comment: I wish static analysis would catch it (would be the best imho), but can see, that it doesn't, so unless i am making a mistake, there is no way. I am looking for a clean alternative to solve the issue, e.g. using a non-null-assertion (which wouldn't be fully safe, in case someone does add a reassignment), optional chaining (which adds a check to the emitted code, for no reason), etc. So far, it seems like hoisting `createInterface` out of the `try` is the best choice, as it seems to be considerably safe, that it can't throw (from what i can read here).

Comment: Unlike a non-null-assertion, if static analysis were to understand it, it would be safe. Should a programmer accidentally add a reassignment later, only then would an error appear at compile-time. However, as mentioned, it's understandable, that such analysis isn't (yet?) done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript believes that `rl` might be null at that point because `rl` is mutable, and it might be mutated in between being initialized and the promise being evaluated.

The most straightforward answer would be to initialize `rl` outside of the try-catch. It doesn't seem that `readline.createInterface` can fail directly so:

```ts
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

try {
 // use rl here
} finally {
  rl.close();
}
```

If `readline.createInterface` *could* throw, then the Promise just needs to be accessing the readline interface value through a const reference. e.g.

```ts
let rl: Readline.Interface | null = null;

try {
    rl = readline.createInterface({ /* ... snip */ });
    const readlineInterface = rl;
    const question = async (questionText: string): Promise<string> => 
        new Promise((resolve) => {
            readlineInterface.question(`${questionText}\n`, resolve)
        });
} finally {
    rl?.close();
}
```

This example is a little bit contrived but shows the idea well enough.

Also consider splitting initialization and reading into separate try-catch blocks:

```ts
let rl: readline.Interface;

try {
    rl = readline.createInterface({ /* ... snip */ });
} catch (err) {
    // handle errors
}

if (!rl) {
    // handle rl not being instantiated
}

try {
    // use rl here
} finally {
    rl.close();
}
```

Comment: For the specific scenario, this seems to be the best approach. I did not consider, that it is quite certain, that `createInterface` cannot throw. In case `createInterface` could throw, it looks like creating a copy in an additional variable inside the `try`-block (which can even be `const`, and will not have `null` in its type), and using that, is "as clean as it gets".

Comment: Yes, as long as typescript can be sure that the reference you're accessing is const and has a value, you'll be fine. That includes what you suggested, by assigning the let-bound `rl` to a const binding that the promise internals can access. I'll add that as part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this would be to call `createInterface` immediately, and put the `try`/`finally` *after* it:

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
});
try {
  const question = async (questionText: string) => new Promise<string>(res => void rl.question(`${questionText}\n`, answer => void res(answer)));
  // other stuff that might throw
} finally {
  rl.close();
}
```